# Download Safari 8 for Windows

Tags: windows, safari

I'm trying to find Safari 8 for Windows as I am programming a website and I want to see if it all works properly in the Safari browser.
I got Windows 8 and the Application Server and the database both run locally on my PC right now.
Is there a way to test the website on Safari 8 without having a Mac or iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of Safari for Windows was 5.1.7, then they discontinued the Windows version.

But if you want to test how your website renders under Safari, you can use online emulators like [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms).